# Keeping Image Name in ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to keep the name of an image when you merge them to form an ImageCollection

In the below example the images 'constant1' and 'constant2' become '0' and '1'

```js
// Create arbitrary constant images.
var constant1 = ee.Image(1);
var constant2 = ee.Image(2);

// Create a collection by giving a list to the constructor.
var collectionFromConstructor = ee.ImageCollection([constant1, constant2]);
print('collectionFromConstructor: ', collectionFromConstructor);
```

Comment: `constant1` and `constant2` are the names of the variables, not the names of the images. Images have no name, they have an id

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to the image that are kept when you construct a Collection from them.

For instance you can name the bands:

```js
var constant1 = ee.Image(1).rename("constant1");
var constant2 = ee.Image(2).rename("constant2");
```

Or set a new property to the image object:

```js
var constant1 = ee.Image(1).set(my_image_name: "constant1"});
var constant2 = ee.Image(2).set({my_image_name: "constant2"});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code editor displays images in a collection using the system:id property of each image, if there is one.

```
// Create arbitrary constant images.
var constant1 = ee.Image(1).set("system:id", "image1")
var constant2 = ee.Image(2).set("system:id", "image2")

// Create a collection by giving a list to the constructor.
var collectionFromConstructor = ee.ImageCollection([constant1, constant2]);
print('collectionFromConstructor: ', collectionFromConstructor);
```